# How do I remove Google (and other apps) passwords from a Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, passwords

I am leaving a job and have to return the laptop that is running Windows 7  and Chrome. I am reading around about how to remove saved passwords and auto-fills, but I would like to clearly understand that I am doing it for this particular computer without any influence on how google works for me on other devices.

Comment: This is a laptop with Windows 7 and Chrome on it

Answer (score -1):

Open your browser. Go to settings. Once in settings enable advance settings. And scroll down until you see privacy. Go to clear browsing data and go to advanced. Where it says Time Range you want to do "All time" and check all the options you want off that particular computer. And hit clear data. The way you will notice it is only for that computer is that if you do the same on another computer you will get different results as in the number of items you see under the things you are clearing. It only refers to that computer and clearing data from one computer will not clear data from your other devices, as long as they are not synced. And if you think they are just turn sync off and then do that for a better peace of mind.

Comment: Thanks. However it does not solve my main issue.
IThere are still items that are '"global"and shared with all other devices. 
What I need is to prevent anyone who receives this machine from accessing my data